# Multiprocessing arcpy python run from batch file

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, arcpy

So I'm trying to add multiprocessing capability to a python script that's run via a batch file. I keep getting a traceback type error when run and can't seem to trouble shoot it. The most I can puzzle out of the error is that it says Medcen function does not exist. But I thought that was the purpose of the def (see below).

**EDIT**

Code has been edited to reflect current state after suggestions.

So I see now that part of my issue is I'm trying to convert a for loop to a multiprocess. Where I could do an incrementing variable via x = x+1 to modify the output filenames I now need to find another way to do that. But that's not the entire problem. I've attempted using enumerate but that doesn't work either.

**Batch file code:**

```
C:\PathToArcPython2.7-64bit C:\PathtoScript3
```

**Script 3 Code multiprocessing attempt:**

```
import arcpy
import os
import fnmatch
import sys
import multiprocessing
#==============================================================================     
working_dir = r'E:\PathToDir'
output_dir = os.path.join(working_dir, 'Results')
if not os.path.isdir(output_dir):
    os.mkdir(output_dir)
#============================================================================== 
global input_files5
global input_files6
input_files5 = []
input_files6 = []
#==============================================================================
for r, d, f in os.walk(output_dir):
    for inFile in fnmatch.filter(f, '*Processed.shp'):
        input_files5.append(os.path.join(r, inFile))

global num
num = enumerate([0,1])

def Script(file):
    name = output_dir + "\\" + "Prefix" + str(num) + "Script.shp"
    arcpy.Tool(file, name,"","", "Field1;Field2") 
    input_files6.append(name)
    print "Script " + str(num)

def MCprocess():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(Script, input_files5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    working_dir = r'E:\PathToDir'
    output_dir = os.path.join(working_dir, 'Results')
    input_files5 = []
    input_files6 = []
    for r, d, f in os.walk(output_dir):
        for inFile in fnmatch.filter(f, '*Processed.shp'):
            input_files5.append(os.path.join(r, inFile))
    MCprocess()
```

**StackTraceError**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Path\To\Script.py", line 55, in <module>
    MCprocess()
  File "Path\To\Script.py", line 41, in MCprocess
    pool.map(Script, input_files5)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.5\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.5\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output 
Path\To\File\Prefix_<enumerate object at 0x0000000012CCB678>Suffix.shp
Failed to execute (Script).
```

Comment: Could you post the error? And check if there is anything in args after you set it? You may just need to add a 'global input_files5' after def MCprocess():

Comment: @IanE The error I am currently receiving when entering line by line in a python instance occurs as follows. When I finish the def MCprocess, I type McProcess(). The error is AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Medcen'

Comment: Stack trace? I need more information. Have you tried not setting target=Medcen and just puting Medcen in pool.map()?

Comment: I don't really know how to do a Stack trace. I'm coming from a GIS type background so I'm kind of spotty on somethings. The traceback error hasn't appeared again. I attempted without defining target and args and just putting Medcen and input_files5 directly in pool.map EDIT: the traceback error only appears when run from batch file.

Comment: Added the error after working out how to print it to a log file.

Comment: @IanE I have narrowed the current error down to how I'm trying to iterate/increment the naming.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you are accessing/changing it with multiple threads at a time. I would take a look into exclusive locks. I haven't done a lot of locking in python (so dont use this as actual code) but it should look something like 1) lock num 2) increment num 3) store value of num locally for use 4) unlock num

Comment: @IanE I found a way to do it without locking. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was trying to iterate in the same as with a for loop. Instead I decided to do it with the original file names which are already unique at this stage of the processing. Relevant code below.

```
def Medcen(file):

    filename = str(file)
    filename = filename.split('\\')
    filename = filename[-1]
    filename = filename.strip('Processed.shp')

    name = output_dir + "\\" + str(filename) + "MedCen.shp"

    arcpy.MedianCenter_stats(file, name,"","", "Field1;Field2") 
    input_files6.append(name)
    print "Med Cen " + str(filename)
```